# cvs no longer works on mac os x sierra from remote terminal

Tags: macos, cvs, macos-sierra

After updating to mac os x sierra my cvs (yes I am still using cvs) repository is no longer accessible from remote computer. I can still access the cvs commands on local machine using terminal window, using:

```
CVSROOT=/usr/local/cvsrep
```

although if I define the cvs variables with

```
export CVS_RSH=ssh
export CVSROOT=:ext:twarren@tw-imac.local/usr/local/cvsrep
```

it also does not work, giving error message:

```
tw-imac:testcvs twarren$ cvs version
Client: Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.13 (client/server)
Password:
bash: cvs: command not found
```

The cvs program is installed in /usr/local/bin (which is on the PATH). It is the old version of cvs that used to come with mac os x and has worked fine with newer versions of mac os x until sierra.

Comment: Same problem here, I tried to install cvs with homebrew but still not working

Comment: yes, the problem seems to be that after the ssh authentication succeeds, the bash shell that gets started does not contain /usr/local/bin directory and so "cvs command not found" error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I've just faced this same issue.

ie, remote cvs checkouts don't work.

ie, `cvs -z3 -d:ext:<user>@<cvs-server-ip>:<CVSROOT> co -P -r <REVISION> <MODULE>` results in `cvs: bad command`

**There are three problems**,

1. cvs was removed back in 10.9
2. cvs over ssh relies on the sshd PATH support, which is hard-coded
3. /usr/bin is rootless, ie read-only.

**You solve the first problem by installing cvs with homebrew**

- Install homebrew see: https://brew.sh
- then `brew install cvs`

**The next problem, is that when you try to run cvs:ext, you find the PATH is not right**, this can be tested like so:

`ssh <user>@cvs-sever-ip env | grep PATH`

You will see, `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, which is the sshd non-interactive hard-coded path. For non-interactive ssh, as used by CVS to access the homebrew cvs install (installed into `/usr/local/bin/cvs) you need to add /usr/local/bin to the sshd path. AFAICT this can't be done... non-trivially... as such, the best solution is to make a sybolic link in the /usr/bin directory.

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cvs /usr/bin/cvs`

**Which leads to the third problem**. It doesn't work, because /usr/bin is rootless... and thus read-only.

You could disable rootless mode in recovery mode... and then do it, and then re-enable it.

**But the simplest solution is** to reboot into Recovery mode, enter the terminal, then cd /Volumes, then navigate to the the /usr/bin directory on your boot volume, ie `cd /Volumes/<bootvolume>/usr/bin`

then run the command:

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/cvs cvs`

This will create a symbolic link from /usr/bin/cvs -> /usr/local/bin/cvs

Reboot back to your OS, and that should fix it.

You can verify this with

`ssh <user>@<cvs-server-ip> which cvs`

which should return :

`/usr/bin/cvs`

**And now your remote cvs checkouts should work...**

Answer (score 2):

so I found a way to get cvs to work on sierra. The problem seemed to be that the /usr/local/bin directory was no longer on the path of the shell started by ssh. So the solution consisted of copying the cvs executable to /usr/bin

However, in order to accomplish this on Sierra I had to temporarily disable SIP. This was done by:

1. reboot with recovery mode
2. run terminal utility
3. execute: csrutil disable
4. reboot

Then I could copy the cvs program. After verifying that it worked properly, I repeated the steps 1-4, except using: csrutil enable in step 3.

NOTE: there will probably be cases where updates to Sierra might replace /usr/bin contents, so it's possible that this process will need to be repeated after updates. To aid in this, I copied the cvs module rather than moving it, so it will still be available in its old location.

NOTE 2: I agree with those who recommend using git rather than cvs and will do that with all new projects. In addition I will eventually also convert existing projects to git where feasible, but am glad that I can still use cvs as before Sierra.

Comment: Great! Worked for me. Don't forget to reenable SIP again after copying the file!